# Compiler can't find PostAsJsonAsync method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC 5 razor application that calls a RESTful API web service..  One of the calls in the API uses a POST method.  I have this line in my code:

```
var response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/account/AddUserAccount", item).Result;
```

Now, I was able to build that line without any errors displaying, but when I build the application, I get

> 'HttpClient' does not contain a definition for 'PostAsJsonAsync' and no extension method 'PostAsJsonAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpClient' could be found

I've done a search on the error and I've found posts on Stack Overflow that say to add a reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll, but I can't find that DLL on my system. How do I fix this error?

Comment: You mean this [System.Net.Http.Formatting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension/) ?

Comment: I installed that but it didn't fix the problem. Now I get messages about not being able to resolve System.Net.Http and The dependency System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension 5.2.3 in project TestAccountService does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0.

Comment: If you're using DNX then you cannot use PostAsJsonAsync method.
Try the following: `var response = await client.PostAsync("api/values", new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);, Encoding.UTF8,"application/json"));`

Comment: I was able to get your second suggestion to compile. Thanks. If you make it an answer I'll give you credit for it.

Comment: @TonyVitabile - I just summarized all comments into the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you gonna use `PostAsJsonAsync` method then you need to use following [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension/).

However, if you're using DNX that it won't work because it does not support DNX (yet?).

It that case you can do the following:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync("api/values", new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);, Encoding.UTF8,"application/json"));
```

That should help.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an using statement.

```
using System.Net.Http; /* probably this one */
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
```

Of course, that using statement is no good, unless you have
System.Net.Http.Formatting(.dll)
referenced (as you found out in your search)

**This dll comes from a nuget package !**

Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client

Most recent link:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/

The version I have here (where I found my copy of that .dll)

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/4.0.20710

Comment: The only DLLs I see in the Add Reference dialogs are System.Net.dll and System.Net.Http.dll; I do not see System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll

Comment: You need to "Manage Nuget Packages" for your csproj.